# Looking for a chassidic Torah commentary on the level of Pshat

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, chasidut-hasidism, pardes

I'm looking for a chassidic Torah commentary on the level of pshat or a chassidic commentary easy to read?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mattheus and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Hello Matheus and welcome. Do you have any language requirements or limitations for your question? Or are you fluent in Hebrew, Aramaic and Yiddish?

Comment: Hebrew language

Comment: Unfortunately, it is out of stock at the moment from the publisher. But if you can find the Lubavitcher Rebbe's commentary on Rashi, it may be exactly what you are looking for. I would try Ebay. Here's the set: https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HRE-BIURPR.S

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of seforim called [Maayanos Hepshat](https://www.sefer.org.il/Product/36154626/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%98-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94---%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) by Rav Dovid Fink which is exactly what you are looking for, unfortunately, it seems that the set isn't available in the states right now.

Answer (score 1):

https://store.kehotonline.com/mobile/prodinfo.asp?number=ESE-TORA.LSE

A great chumash that tries to render the simple meaning of chumash in it's translation/commentary (while being consistent with Torah Shebal Peh)  and beautiful chassidic insights as well.

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/51842

Answer (score 0):

Likutei Sichos from the Lubavitcher Rebbe has many talks that explain the parsha according to Chassidus. (It does include also talks that are more על דרך פשט